# JPA: single database field, multiple times in different fomr on that same Entity

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, entity

Like in a topic...
How can I get that same field from database in one single entity but in two different types....

i.e.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROOMS")
public class Rooms implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID_ROOM")

private int idRoom;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_HOTEL")
private Hotel hotel;
//and right here I need a something like

@JoinColumn(name = "ID_HOTEL")
private int hotelId;
```

but.... I need it only for doing some searches using EL... I dont need it for inserting or updateing....

Comment: You are aware that instead of `Rooms.hotelId = ?` you can use `Rooms.hotel.id = ?` and vice-versa?

Comment: It didnt work with CriteriaQuery:/ im trying to create abstract DAO with filtering for fields for LazyDataModel from PrimeFaces...

Comment: What didnt work exactly? Did you fetch your sub object in your criteria query?

Comment: Well....

    @Column(name="ID_HOTEL", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private int hotelId;

with only getter method resolve my problem... thanks a lot anyway:)

Answer (score 4):

Your hotelId is a @Basic, so you must use @Column not @JoinColumn.  You should also set one of the columns as insertable/updateable=false, as you are mapping it twice.